# How to increase pinout switching?

Tags: digital, speed, digitalwrite

Consider this code:

```
void loop() {
    digitalWrite(pinTest, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(pinTest, LOW);
}
```

On an Arduino Mega 2560, running 16MHz (=0.06us), I would expect the width of the pulse to be somewhere around 0.1us.

However, when measuring with my oscilloscope, I get around 4us high and 5-6 us low. I understand it could take some cycles to run the `digitalWrite` code, but this seems quite a lot.

How is that difference explained?

Comment: digitalWrite is not optimized to translate the value of `pinTest` to the proper port/bit combination.  If you need that, do it once in advance. Your code will be hardware-specific for avr-gcc targets.

Comment: @DataFiddler any resources on how to do that in advance?

Comment: Watch this youtube [Why I’m switching over from the awesome Arduino IDE to Atmel Studio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=648Tx5N9Zoc)

Comment: Thanks all. Too bad, I am on Linux, so Atmel Studio is not an option, but I found a wait to build assembly code using `arduino-cli` and Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to go all the way down to assembly in order to get that
speed. You can do direct port access from your `.ino` file:

```cpp
void setup() {
    DDRA |= _BV(PA0);  // pin 22 = PA0 as output
    for (;;) {
        PINA |= _BV(PA0);  // toggle PA0
    }
}

void loop(){}
```

This compiles to something that is almost equivalent to your assembly
code. Actually, it is a bit faster, as it uses `rjmp` instead of the
slower `jmp` instruction.

**Edit**: A few notes

1. As pointed out by timemage in a comment, you can save another CPU
   cycle by writing `PINA =` instead of `PINA |=`.
2. This code, as well as your two examples, will exhibit a glitch every
   1,024 µs. This is caused by the periodic timer interrupt used
   by the Arduino core for timekeeping (`millis()`, `micros()` and
   `delay()`). You can avoid the glitch by disabling interrupts before
   going into the tight loop. Alternatively, if you do not use the
   Arduino core at all, you can define a function called `main()`
   instead of `setup()` and `loop()`: this will completely remove the
   Arduino core initialization for your compiled program.
3. `arduino-cli` is useful for sparing you the complexity of the Arduino
   build system (automatic installation of the cores and libraries,
   libraries in multiple places that depend on the core you use...). If
   you do not use the Arduino core, `arduino-cli` is of little use: a
   very simple Makefile that calls `avr-gcc` and `avrdude` is all you
   need for basic AVR development.

Comment: `PINA =` rather than `PINA |=`.  I'm not 100% certain what will happen with the `SBI` that `PINA |= expr` appears to be generating; but it if actually behaves as `PINA = PINA | expr` it is trying to toggle port pins in part based on the current read value of the port. In any case, `PINA = ` is sufficient and winds up generating an `OUT` which is 1 cycle compared to `SBI`'s two cycles. It's peanuts. But then they are going for speed.

Comment: @timemage: You are right, `PINA =` is faster here. `sbi` is safe, as it is a real bitwise access, not a bytewise read-modify-write. `PINA |=`, on the other hand, is only safe when you know `PINA` lives in the bit-addressable part of the I/O space.

Comment: I suspected that about `sbi` simply because it would be much less useful otherwise.  Re. I/O space: Yeah I didn't spell it out, but `PINH`/`PINJ`/`PINK`/`PINL` (curiously no `PINI`; perhaps it looks too much like a 1) all result `lds`,`ori`,`sts`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using assembly code to run the program. Because I am using Linux, I couldn't use Atmel Studio, but you can easily use AVR assembly with `arduino-cli`.

Make your `.ino` like this:

```
extern "C" void myAssemblyMain();

void setup() {
    myAssemblyMain();
}
void loop() {
}
```

then add a `pulse.S` file with the assembly code:

```
#define __SFR_OFFSET 0

#include "avr/io.h"

.global myAssemblyMain

myAssemblyMain:
  sbi   DDRA, 0     ; Set PA0 as output

blink:
  sbi   PINA, 0     ; Toggle PINB
  jmp   blink
```

Using this code, I get a ~400ns pulse. Which is more than enough for my needs.

Comment: you can do the same with the Arduino IDE. no need for CLI

Comment: please update your question, because this does not answer the question you asked

Comment: @jsotola agreed it didn't answer the exact question, but it does give another way of reaching the same goal.

Comment: @Juraj thanks, I'll check that out. But I work a lot with Visual Studio Code, so staying within the same tool is preferable.